# rosdep key for SDL2 not working

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-humble

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
ROS2 Distro: Humble

I ran this command inside the directory that contains the src folder for all my ROS packages.

```
rosdep install -y -r --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=humble
```

However, I got this error:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
keyboard_teleop: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [libsdl2-dev]
Continuing to install resolvable dependencies...
#All required rosdeps installed successfully
```

But the rosdep key I used "libsdl2-dev" is from the official rosdep key github: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/0bec75fd1305910808b07776fbd1997a8c315998/rosdep/base.yaml (line 4651)

I thought putting the line

```
<depend>libsdl2-dev</depend>
```

inside the package.xml file of the package allows rosdep to find and install the necessary dependencies of the package.

Is there something I did wrong? I am new to managing dependencies with rosdep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the right entry. However you should be referencing the parent key, not the platform specific package.

So `sdl2` and then on your platform rosdep will determine that it should install `libsdl2-dev` on other platforms it will resolve appropriately using the other rules.

Our default is to use the Debian/Ubuntu naming policy so most are the same and likely your source of confusion. However this is an older legacy rule so doesn't match exactly.